# Add transition to collapsible data table

Tags: javascript, css

Here's what I have right now is https://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/gaGBZz
I want to add a collapse transition to the data table.

Please visit the link to see the whole example
Please Help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function(){
  $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
 });
});
```

```css
table { 
 width: 750px; 
 border-collapse: collapse; 
 margin:50px auto;
 }

th { 
 background: #3498db; 
 color: white; 
 font-weight: bold; 
 }

td, th { 
 padding: 10px; 
 border: 1px solid #ccc; 
 text-align: left; 
 font-size: 18px;
 }

.labels tr td {
 background-color: #2cc16a;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
}

.label tr td label {
 display: block;
}


[data-toggle="toggle"] {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Regian</th>
   <th>Q1 2010</th>
   <th>Q2 2010</th>
   <th>Q3 2010</th>
   <th>Q4 2010</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tbody class="labels">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
     <label for="accounting">Accounting</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="accounting" id="accounting" data-toggle="toggle">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hide">
   <tr>
    <td>Australia</td>
    <td>$7,685.00</td>
    <td>$3,544.00</td>
    <td>$5,834.00</td>
    <td>$10,583.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Central America</td>
    <td>$7,685.00</td>
    <td>$3,544.00</td>
    <td>$5,834.00</td>
    <td>$10,583.00</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="labels">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
     <label for="management">Management</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="management" id="management" data-toggle="toggle">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hide">
   <tr>
    <td>Australia</td>
    <td>$7,685.00</td>
    <td>$3,544.00</td>
    <td>$5,834.00</td>
    <td>$10,583.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Central America</td>
    <td>$7,685.00</td>
    <td>$3,544.00</td>
    <td>$5,834.00</td>
    <td>$10,583.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Europe</td>
    <td>$7,685.00</td>
    <td>$3,544.00</td>
    <td>$5,834.00</td>
    <td>$10,583.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Middle East</td>
    <td>$7,685.00</td>
    <td>$3,544.00</td>
    <td>$5,834.00</td>
    <td>$10,583.00</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>  
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can follow this http://jsfiddle.net/9ccjE/ fiddle, see if you can find something.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example: using [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('thead').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

```css
table { 
 width: 750px; 
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  width: 100%;
}

th { 
 background: #3498db; 
 color: white; 
 font-weight: bold; 
}

td, th { 
 padding: 10px; 
 border: 1px solid #ccc; 
 text-align: left; 
 font-size: 18px;
 }

.labels tr td {
 background-color: #2cc16a;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
}

.label tr td label {
 display: block;
}


[data-toggle="toggle"] {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Accounting</th></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>Australia</td>
    <td>$7,685.00</td>
    <td>$3,544.00</td>
    <td>$5,834.00</td>
    <td>$10,583.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Central America</td>
    <td>$7,685.00</td>
    <td>$3,544.00</td>
    <td>$5,834.00</td>
    <td>$10,583.00</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to get the transition you wanted, but you'll have to restyle some elements. In order to manipulate the height of table elements you have to make them display block, which tends to mess up the style a bit. You should be able to get it back, just have to play with some widths and heights a little. But here is the updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/joeybreithaupt/pen/aQQGjE), I hope its what you were looking for! I wrote the JS vanilla, hope thats okay.

```
display: block;
```

Comment: And a quick addition for the future, height itself cannot be animated, but max-height can be. You'll notice I used max-height in the pen for the collapsing and growing effect.